# Control Key Sometimes Work

Tags: keyboard

It is becoming very frustrating and embarrassing that my control key occasionally works. It makes it hard to perform fast work when using keyboard shortcuts, for example: crtl-c, crtl-v etc.

### Problem:

- Problem occurred before
- Happens from time to time, then goes away and then returns
- **Both** Control keys are not operational. (I use Left Crtl most, Right Crtl hardly use)

### My Environment

- Windows 7 32-bit, Professionally Genuine ;)
- Toshiba Laptop, Model: Satellite Pro A300, 1.3 years old.
- In-built keyboard = problematic (PS/2 w/ Standard MS-Driver v. 6.1.7600.16385 [Latest])

### Trouble-shooting attempts

- In-bulit: Because **both** left & right ctrl keys are not working (I only use left), I assumed that it shouldn't be a hardware issue.
- Tried New USB Keyboard, new ctrl keys works.
- Guess it may be a driver issue??

Please help,

Lee (Advanced User is stuck)

Answer (score 1):

**Welcome to Superuser.**

Laptop keyboards get more abuse than most standard ones. They are made smaller, lighter and less sturdy by nature of their placement. They also tend to get a lot more material dropped or spilled on them. Even thought this may sound rather elementary, you should try using compressed air to blow out any debris which may be under the keys.

Make sure your BIOS are up to date and that you have the latest drivers from Toshiba for your laptop (not just what Windows Update offers).

Since an external keyboard works without error, it is possible something is wrong with the built in keyboard. I found them on eBay for about $30, so if the above doesn't work it might be worth the investment to just replace it.